# Is "is" ommited before "a cancer"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

In *Fight Club (1999)*, Narrator speaks to faker at support groups:

> Narrator: I can't cry if another faker is present, and I need this. So
> you gotta find somewhere else to go.
>
> Faker: **Candy-stripe a cancer ward**. It's not my problem.

Is "is" ommited before "a cancer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Candy strip" is functioning as a verb.

A "candy striper" is a [volunteer nurse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hospital_volunteer) (from the narrow striped pinafores that they traditionally wore), so "Candy-stripe a cancer ward" means "Work as volunteer in a cancer ward".